# How to convert my TSQL query to LINQ

Tags: linq, t-sql, converters

I am new to linq. I can't convert this SQL code to linq. Please help me. Thanks.

```
DECLARE @myHID BIGINT;
SET @myHID = 1;

WITH tblChild AS
(
     SELECT *
     FROM wbs.WBS w 
     WHERE w.ParentId = @myHID

     UNION ALL

     SELECT w2.* 
     FROM wbs.WBS w2  
     JOIN tblChild ON w2.ParentId = tblChild.hID
)
SELECT
    tblChild.hID , 
    Unit.ID, w3.wbsName + ' * ' + tblChild.wbsName as 
    structure , 
    tblChild.FK_WbsBaseStructure_hID , 
    tblChild.parentID , 
    unitNumber , 
    unitTitle , 
    FK_UsageItem_ID, 
    usageTitle , 
    nominalArea
FROM 
    tblChild
INNER JOIN
    unit.Unit ON tblChild.hID = Unit.FK_WBS_hID
INNER JOIN
    unit.UsageItem ON Unit.FK_UsageItem_ID = UsageItem.ID
LEFT JOIN
    wbs.WBS w3 ON tblChild.parentID = w3.hID
```

Please convert this to linq code.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a free conversion service. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Format your code properly, how does your ORM Mappings look like? Do you use NHibernate or EF / EF Core? And more important, what do you tried to get it work? Please read what @RacilHilan posted.

Comment: i am using LINQ for EF.
but i can' t convert this sample to LINQ

Comment: you can't carry on asking translation services without any attempts to deal with your problem in the first place https://stackoverflow.com/users/3425037/user3425037

Answer (score 1):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (DISTINCT, TOP, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (new { }) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a into join_variable and doing another from from the join variable followed by .DefaultIfEmpty().
6. Replace COALESCE with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. SELECT * must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
8. SELECT fields must be replaced with select new { ... } creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
9. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.